# WCF client proxy - what is instance per thread best practice?

Tags: wcf, proxy, client

What are the best practices for managing a single instance of a WCF client proxy per thread? I am using a WIF secured WCF service with a generated client proxy. I am using token caching to reduce the overhead of calling the STS for each call, and this is working successfully. However I am constructing the proxy using one of the non-standard constructors, that prevents caching - [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx)

For more efficient management of the client proxy I am wanting to cache the client proxy so that there is a single instance per thread. What are the best practices for this?

- Should I always explicitly call `.Open()`
- Should I ever call `.Close()`
- Should I always check the `State` of the channel before using it, and initialise a new proxy if it is in the `Faulted` state (and call `.Abort()` on the old one)?

Are there any other best practices I should be aware of?

Comment: It strongly depends on the way how your service works. Do you have stateless or statefull binding?

Comment: the service is secured using WIF, and uses WS2007FederationHttpBinding, but the service is not stateful. I would like to avoid negotiating the security context on each call too, to further reduce overhead.

Comment: If you don't want to negotiate security for each call you must reuse proxy and use secure conversation => stateful service because secure conversation will create security session.

Comment: Without a cached proxy I'm hitting limits after calling a method 10 times. I had an async method that wasn't disposing of the proxy correctly in the "End". I understand that this is due to the MaxConcurrentSessions setting on the service. I'm increasing this limit (I'm on 3.5, and note that with 4.0 they've been increased) I'm assuming if I was caching the proxy I'd be far less likely to hit the limit? I also realise that if I cache, I can't use "Using". Are timeouts btw client/service a concern (i.e. if proxy is cached)? Should I cache, or use using? Any further advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Timeouts are concern because if timeout expires the next call on proxy will fire exception. Also if you do not handle closing correctly you will leak sessions unit they timeouts. But perhaps you can reuse token received from STS (federation).